# AnimationSet defined via XML does not repeat

Tags: android, xml, android-animation

I have this xml code, that should simulate a sort of "heart beat" animation. Image that use it should scale twice, and return to original size, then restart again:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:repeatCount="-1"
android:repeatMode="restart"
android:shareInterpolator="true" >

<scale
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="1.2"
    android:toYScale="1.2" />
<scale
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXScale="1.2"
    android:fromYScale="1.2"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="1.4"
    android:toYScale="1.4" />
<scale
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXScale="1.4"
    android:fromYScale="1.4"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0" />

</set>
```

and this is how i add this animation set to my imageview:

```
AnimationSet heart_pulse = new AnimationSet(true);
            heart_pulse.addAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity,
                    R.anim.pulsexml));

            logo.setAnimation(heart_pulse);
            logo.startAnimation(heart_pulse);
```

but animation is executed only one time, then it stops. Why?

Comment: android:repeatCount="-1" it should repeat (-1) times

Comment: @pskink take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#INFINITE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Have you tried adding `android:fillAfter="false"`?</strike>

**EDIT:**

According to the documentation sintax of [Animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Property), these properties must be set to an Animatior and not to the set, so let's have then this custom animation **repeating with no code**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <scale
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXScale="1"
        android:fromYScale="1"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="-1"
        android:repeatMode="restart"
        android:toXScale="1.2"
        android:toYScale="1.2" />
    <scale
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXScale="1.2"
        android:fromYScale="1.2"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="-1"
        android:repeatMode="restart"
        android:toXScale="1.4"
        android:toYScale="1.4" />
    <scale
        android:duration="500"
        android:fromXScale="1.4"
        android:fromYScale="1.4"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="-1"
        android:repeatMode="restart"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0" />

</set>
```

Comment: fillafter default value is false

Comment: @giozh You're right, I got confused! I've edited the proper answer.

Comment: for me this disappear the image completely :(

Answer (score 4):

try this custom Interpolator:

```
final ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart);
setContentView(iv);
Runnable action = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Interpolator i = new Interpolator() {
            @Override
            public float getInterpolation(float input) {
                float x = input < 1/3f? 2 * input : (1 + input) / 2;
                return (float) Math.sin(x * Math.PI);
            }
        };
        ScaleAnimation anim = new ScaleAnimation(1, 1.2f, 1, 1.2f, iv.getWidth() / 2, iv.getHeight() / 2);
        anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        anim.setDuration(750);
        anim.setInterpolator(i);
        iv.startAnimation(anim);
    }
};
iv.post(action);
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a [CycleInterpolator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/CycleInterpolator.html) for your animation, e.g.:

```
final Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.pulsexml);
animation.setInterpolator(new CycleInterpolator(3f));
logo.startAnimation(animation);
```