# How to create a Heart Pulse animtion in Android?

Tags: android, animation, graphics

I need to have a Heart Pulse animation in my app such as [this](http://www.istockphoto.com/stock-flash-3834417-ekg-heart-pulse-animation.php) or [this](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/heartbeat/). I don't mind using an external resource as long as I'm able to control the pulse rate. After so much googling many had suggested that the `android.graphics.Path` should be used but then I have no idea of how should I get what I need.

So if anyone knows how to achieve such a thing ?

Comment: The easy way: use an **animated GIF**. The "complex" way, use a series of PNGs in sequence.

Comment: what about standard ScaleAnimation?

Comment: Can you both elaborate please?

Comment: Draw and calculate it in the onDraw :)

Comment: you can use a ScaleAnimation with a custom Interpolator to make effect more realistic, like my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22435906/animationset-defined-via-xml-does-not-repeat/22437308#22437308

Answer (score 15):

You can add a ObjectAnimator like this, creating a pulsating effect in your image

```
ObjectAnimator scaleDown = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(ImageView,
                PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleX", 1.2f),
                PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleY", 1.2f));
        scaleDown.setDuration(300);

        scaleDown.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
        scaleDown.setRepeatMode(ObjectAnimator.REVERSE);

        scaleDown.start();
```

Another way to achive that is have a CustomClass and override your OnDraw method, creating a effect of growing or decrease increasing a variable and recalling invalidate(). I did these in another post to make my button background grow, if you want to follow this way it can be useful for you.

[Pulsating Button Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37263308/pulsating-button-animation-android)