# Android XML Pulse Animation not working as expected

Tags: android, xml, animation, android-animation

I am trying to code an animation that mimics a pulse animation that resembles this:

Concentrate on the **inner** blue circle (ignore the outer dark blue circle)

http://www.joedubs.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/breathe-now.gif

Here's what I managed to code so far:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <scale
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromXScale="1"
        android:fromYScale="1"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="0.8"
        android:toYScale="0.8" />

    <scale
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromXScale="0.8"
        android:fromYScale="0.8"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="2000"
        android:toXScale="1.8"
        android:toYScale="1.8" />

    <scale
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromXScale="1.8"
        android:fromYScale="1.8"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="2000"
        android:toXScale="1"
        android:toYScale="1" />
</set>
```

While this works for a certain extent, the animation skips and stutters when it repeats again. Can someone tweak it a bit to mimic a smooth pulse animation? (grow and reduce)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a ObjectAnimator like this, creating a pulsating effect in the reverse mode:

```
ObjectAnimator scaleDown = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(ImageView,
                PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleX", 0.5f),
                PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleY", 0.5f));
        scaleDown.setDuration(300);

        scaleDown.setRepeatCount(ObjectAnimator.INFINITE);
        scaleDown.setRepeatMode(ObjectAnimator.REVERSE);

        scaleDown.start();
```

Another way to achive that is have a CustomClass and override your OnDraw method, creating a effect of growing or decrease increasing a variable and recalling invalidate(). I did these in another post to make my button background grow, if you want to follow this way it can be useful for you.

[Pulsating Button Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37263308/pulsating-button-animation-android)